# HttpURLConnection GET call with parameters not working

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection

I have a very simple code which is not working.

**Class HttoCon:**

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class HttpCon {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        sendGet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    // HTTP GET request
        private static void sendGet() throws Exception {

            String url = "http://myweb.com/public/resource/data/stream";

            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");


            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("begin", "1430295300000");
            con.setRequestProperty("end", "1430297279988");
            con.setRequestProperty("id", "140621");
            con.setRequestProperty("time", "FIFTEEN_MINUTE");

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            //print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());

        }
}
```

**Error Trace:**

```
{"fault":{"exceptionType":"MissingServletRequestParameterException","host":"12.205.101.123","cause":"Required Long parameter 'id' is not present","status":"400","query":"/public/resource/data/stream","stackTrace":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Long parameter 'id' is not present\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.raiseMissingParameterException(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:774)\n\tat org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestParam(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:509)\n\tat
```

**NOTE:**

If I hit the url directly in browser it works fine.

http://myweb.com/public/resource/data/stream?begin=1430295300000&end=1430297279988&id=140621&time=FIFTEEN_MINUTE

**UPDATE:**

Using curl:

```
curl -X GET http://myweb.com/public/resource/data/stream?begin=1430295300000&end=1430297279988&id=140621&time=FIFTEEN_MINUTE
```

Above curl doesn't work and the exception is same -

```
curl -X GET 'http://myweb.com/public/resource/data/stream?begin=1430295300000&end=1430297279988&id=140621&time=FIFTEEN_MINUTE'
```

This curl works fine.

Comment: try con.setRequestProperty("id", "140621L");

Comment: link doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Pratik - I changed the link just for demo purpose.

Comment: Well if the URL works if you hit it directly in the browser, what speaks against adding the parameters to the request directly by appending them as you do in the Browser, as it looks already that you expect them to be there?

Comment: It looks like setRequestProperty is used to set stuff like "Content-Type" and "User-Agent".  From what I just researched it is not used to set parameters that need to be passed to your code on the url.  For what you are doing, you want to do something like @CraigParkinson did in his answer.

Comment: "curl" needs quoting of the url parameter if e.g. "&" is used ("&" has a special meaning in bash/shell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create a String containing the parameters, which then gets appended onto the URL. Create a URL Obj from this. For example :-

```
String this.url = "http://myweb.com/public/resource/data/stream";
this.url += "?begin=1430295300000&end=1430297279988&id=140621
    &time=FIFTEEN_MINUTE"; 
this.urlObj = new URL(this.url);
```

Then you create the connection as in your original example.

Answer (score 4):

`openConnection` will establish the connection and issue the `GET`. Subsequent settings of `GET` parameters on the returned URLConnection object are ignored, since the URL has already been open.

Add the parameters to the URL as query string params just as the link above and open that link

**or**

try to post the parameters to the server (which is even better)